# Difference Between render($content['body']) and print $body[0]['value']; in node.tpl.php

Tags: nodes

What is the difference between `render($content['body']);` and `print $body[0]['value'];` in node.tpl.php?

`render($content['body']);` seems to include all the fields while `print $body[0]['value'];` includes just the body field.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You kind of answered your own question. `$content['body']` contains everything in a structure in which the render function can turn it into display. This includes all your fields.

`print $body[0]['value']` simply prints the value of that one field bypassing any rendering functionality such as "weight".

Rendering is a fun thing in Drupal, especially when you get to Drupal 7. Think of what you're passing into "render" as instructions on how to output, whereas the `value` is simply... a string... a value.