# Insert Block Inbetween Paragraphs of the Content Body Field

Tags: 7, nodes, blocks

I have a block I am trying to insert into the body field, catch is I want it to appear after the first two paragraphs. I tried using something similar to this in my **node.tpl.php**:

```
<?php
$array = explode ("</p>", $content['body']);
$array[2] = $myBlock . $array[2];
$content['body'] = implode("</p>", $array);
?>

//Important: This code snippet needs to be inserted before

<?php
print $content['body'];
?>
```

This code does insert my block in the body field, but also overwrites all the content in the field.

I'm using Drupal 7.10, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to be doing this on `$body[0]['value'];` And then in your output put `echo render($content['body']);` see the answer to this post [on rendering](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15116/difference-between-rendercontentbody-and-print-body0value-in-node/15128#15128) fields.

Comment: Thank you! Your tip helped me figure it out. Here is how I got it working:

`$array = explode("</p>", $body[0]['value']);
$array[2] = $myBlock . $array[2];
$content['body'] = implode("</p>", $array);`